# Delta function as a probability density distribution?

Tags: probability-theory

What does it mean to define a probability density function as Dirac-delta function. I mean Dirac delta is not a function itself. So how is it considered to be an example of a density function?

I need an exact mathematical definition please. Because in the literature that I am studying it has been used without referring that it might be a problem at all.

Comment: You can think of the Dirac delta function as the "derivative" of the Heaviside function. Perhaps that might help?

Comment: the Dirac can't be defined mathematically be a probability density function, but you can talk about the cumulative distribution function without feeling dirty. (Dirac as a point measure, cdf as heaviside function )

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan, well that is going to be fooling myself. I mean still that derivative is undefined at the origin.

Comment: @Evan, we should be able to defined it mathematically, otherwise I cannot help myself not feeling dirty.

Comment: @Evan No need of a random variable to define a measure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The relevant mathematical notion is the notion of *measure*. A measure $\mu$ is defined on a class of subsets of a space $\Omega$, that is, for some subsets $A\subseteq\Omega$, $\mu(A)$ is a nonnegative real number.

The Dirac measure at $x$, usually denoted $\delta_x$, is the unique measure such that $\delta_x(A)=1$ if $x$ is in $A$ and $\delta_x(A)=0$ otherwise. Note that no Dirac measure has a probability density function. As you noted yourself, when $\Omega=\mathbb R$, for every integrable function $f$, one knows that $\int\limits_{x-\varepsilon}^{x+\varepsilon}f\to0$ when $\varepsilon\to0$ hence one cannot expect to get anything else that $\mu(\{x\})=0$ if $\mu$ has density $f$. By contrast, $\delta_x(\{x\})=1$.

The other interpretations are mostly physics; but beware that physicists are able to manipulate non rigorously defined objects in ways mathematicians cannot.

Now, the rigorous definition when the space is $\Omega=\mathbb R$ endowed with the Borel sigma-algebra $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ (we already explained nearly everything). Then $\delta_x:\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\to\{0,1\}$ is defined by $\delta_x(A)=1$ for every $A$ in $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ such that $x$ is in $A$ and $\delta_x(A)=0$ for every $A$ in $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ such that $x$ is not in $A$. Every Borel function $u$ is measurable with respect to $\delta_x$ and
$$
\int_\mathbb R u\,\mathrm d\delta_x=u(x).
$$
For example, if $u(x)=42$ for every $x\ne0$ and $u(0)=57$, then
$$
\int_\mathbb R u\,\mathrm d\delta_0=57.
$$

Comment: So as you said considering it as a pdf is basically a meaningless invitation by physicists gang, right? I can follow the definition as a measure though.

Answer (score 1):

Probability density functions are applied by integrating over intervals to find your probability of being in the interval. Suppose you knew that you were precisely at the origin, with probability 100%?

Comment: Thanks for the intuition. I can suppose that. But I cannot make a function out if it. I mean mathematically.

Comment: That's why "generalized functions" or distributions, of which Dirac delta is one, are so important. :) This is a totally rigorous notion, just not in the realm of classical functions. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics) if you want to get an inkling ...

Comment: Well as I can follow that existence com from Radon-Nikodym theorem. My problem is according to the theorem, there exist a measurable function and not a generalized measurable function:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_derivative#Radon.E2.80.93Nikodym_derivative

Comment: @Naji  but that theorem needs absolute continuity of measures, but the Dirac measure is singular with respect to lebesgue

Comment: @Evan I think you are right and therefore one cannot even use what I suggested which not only doesn't solve the problem. Makes the puzzle more complex!